# How to fix cracked bathroom tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile

Only two of the tiles are cracked and one portion of grout chipping away (first picture). I think it's because the surface is uneven and poor cushioning. I know people would ideally rip open the whole thing and relevel and lay new tile, but I can't afford that right now. Is there a more economical way to fix this issue and prevent the tiles from cracking in the future?[image]

[image]

Comment: they look like old tiles and probably won't crack more

Comment: They are probably less than 3y old. The previous owners said they had just redone the entire bathroom right before we bought the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two tiles have cracked edge to edge so they are probably done cracking and because of tile distancing, shouldn't affect the next ones. You could clean the tiles, and get some almond colored caulk and try to blend it into the cracks to help hide the cracks. 
Did the tile installer leave any spare tiles for you?

Comment: No but I have seen HD sell this specific color. If you look closer at the first photo, there is a portion of the grout that is chipping away. Is there a different solution for this?

Comment: Good point about the installer leaving extra tiles.  Since I have done most of my own tile work, I have always over-bought - both to allow for mistakes and also to have spares around for situation like this.

Comment: @ShankTesla  The best solution for that would be to get a grout saw and remove the  grout that's chipping away. Try to match  the grout at HD  and re grout  your bad section.  Also, if HD sells those tiles, you might want to pick up a few while they still have them.... just in case you feel energetic some day.